# Displaying wp post categories into my custom metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, metabox

Is there a way to display custom select box containing list of WordPress posts categories in my metabox?

(also my metabox in custom post)

Here are the illustrations:

> This are categories from built-in WordPress post type

[image]

> And this one is metabox from my cutom post type, how to display WordPress categories into this dropdown list ?

[image]

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is typically "yes". Please elaborate on how are you implementing metabox, what have you tried and what specific issues had you encountered trying to achieve it.

Comment: How you are displaying the meta-box ? have you used any custom metabox plugin ?( like Rilwis's )

A category dropdown can be generated like this:
`wp_dropdown_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'select_name', 'hierarchical' => true));`

Comment: no, i create my own metabox using custom html inside it, ah thanks, it's seen on my dropdown now. and just save it with categories ID inside dropdown menu,right ?.